# trying to implement a search in .net MVC

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I am having a tough time figuring out how to do this.  I have added a search box to the main page of my site.  The site has various products you can buy divided into categories.  When you click one of the categories(for instance Candles and Scents), it takes you to /Home/Products/candles-scents.  Now I have created new methods in my controller and model which correctly do the search.  My search function is basically duplicating my "product categories" function, only the sql query is modified.  So I want the site to go to the products page again, just like for a specific category: /Home/Products/"search".  I'm not sure if I should wrap my search box in a form or if there is a better way.  Right now I am trying jquery ajax, but of course the page is not getting redirected.

Here is my search box html:

```
<input type="text" class="search" placeholder="search" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'search'"/>
```

And here is my jquery:

```
$(".search").keypress(function (event) {
        var searchString = $(this).val();
        console.log(searchString);
        console.log("blah");
        if (event.which == 13) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("_search", "Home")',
                data: {
                    search: searchString
                }
            })
        }
    });
```

And here is the _search function in the controller:

```
public ActionResult _search(string search)
    {

        // get the model
        List<ProductModel> m = new List<ProductModel>();

        m = ProductsModel.getProductsBySearch(search);

        return View(m);
    }
```

Then that function simply calls runs the sql query and returns a list of appropriate ProductModel's.  I have the backend stuff figured out.  I am just not sure how to correctly call my search from the front end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you don't want Ajax here if you are returning a complete view.

Consider this javascript to do the redirection without a form:

```
$(".search").keypress(function (event) {
    var searchString = $(this).val();
    console.log(searchString);
    console.log("blah");
    if (event.which == 13) {
        var searchUrl = '@Url.Action("_search", "Home")';
        searchUrl += "/" + searchString;
        window.location.href = searchUrl;
    } // end if
});
```

Or, using a forms approach

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(".search").keypress(function (event) {
    var searchString = $(this).val();
    console.log(searchString);
    console.log("blah");
    if (event.which == 13) {
        $("#search-form").submit();
    } // end if
});
</script>

<form id="search-form" method="post" action="@Url.Action("_search", "Home")">
   <input type="text" class="search" name="search" placeholder="search" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'search'"/>
   <input type="submit" value="Go" name="submit" />
</form>
```

The important piece I added was the `name="search"` attribute to your input.  This tells the default MVC ModelBinder to find the HTML input element with a name matching your controller's action parameter (missing in your source).

Comment: I tried the forms method.  "The view '_search' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations."

Comment: @dmikester1 In your action method, you return View(m).  By default MVC will assume that the name of the view you are returning will match the method name of the action (inside of a folder with your controller name).  If you don't have a view named _search, that will be the issue.  If you want it to return a different view such as the view you use for your product search results, simply have it return: View("ViewIWantToReturn", m); otherwise you'll have to create the view _search.

Answer (score 0):

You can use success function to prevent a page reload

```
$(".search").keyup(function (e) {
    var searchString = $(this).val();
    if (e.which == 13) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("_search", "Home")',
            data: {
                search: searchString
            },
            success: function () {
                // do something here, like replace the html
            }
        });
    }
});
```

One tip from conventions, use your action name like this

```
public ActionResult Search(string search)
```